# derived type as argument to template accepting base

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to pass a derived template type as argument to a template that accepts a base type ?
Why do I get this incomplete type - nested name specifier error ?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <tuple>
    #include <typeinfo>
    #include <cxxabi.h>

    using namespace std;

    template<typename ...Types> struct derivedTuple : public std::tuple<Types...> {};

    int main() {
        int     status;

        cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(
                    tuple_element<0,
                        std::tuple<int, char, const char *>  // works
                    >::type
                ).name(),0,0,&status) << endl;

        cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(
                    tuple_element<0,
                    derivedTuple<int, char, const char *>  // error: incomplete type 'std::tuple_element<0u, derivedTuple<int, char, const char*> >' used in nested name specifier
                    >::type
                ).name(),0,0,&status) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Templates require perfect matching of the arguments, unlike regular functions, no conversions are performed, not even derived to base.

Comment: Thanks, Yes indeed and the way to achieve this behavior is through specializations.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard [`std::tuple_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) is undefined for types other than `std::tuple`. You can implement those specialisations if you want, though, even by forwarding to the `tuple` variant.

Comment: Thanks. I guess will have to write my own specializations. Although if the base type is std::tuple stl could have easily provided this by forwarding to the std:tuple implementation.

Comment: If it did, you would have no chance overriding it. Also, it is not so easy to specialize for subclasses.